# Passing array to function - array is empty inside function

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, json, function

I tried almost everything, I have two codes:

First one, pokaz_ofe, calls correct function - "generuj_oferte" in ajaxQuery() function, but I cant access postTab array in ajaxQuery(). Without delete postData it was using old array from another call (other that in "pokaz_ofe" function).

```
function ajaxQuery(postData, func_var) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/pokaz_lst.php",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        success: func_var
    })
    postData = [];
    delete postData;
}
function pokaz_ofe(id,tab) {
    if(!tab) {
      var postTab = [
        { "id": id }
      ]
    }
    else {
      var postTab = [
        { "id": id },
        { "listaId": tab}
      ]
    }
    ajaxQuery(postTab, generuj_oferte);
}
function generuj_oferte(res) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#modal-oferta').html( res );
    });
}
```

And this is the different code which works, but I want it more flexible:

```
function pokaz_ofe(id,tab) {
    if(!tab) {
      var postData = [
        { "id": id }
      ]
    }
    else {
      var postData = [
        { "id": id },
        { "listaId": tab}
      ]
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/pokaz_ofe.php",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        success: generuj_oferte
    })
}
```

Comment: You should pass it inside a function, declaring its scope inside an anonymous function `succes: function(res){ general_offerte(res); }`, thats will allow you to access it.

Comment: works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/9kkjuzjx/   without the `delete` call: http://jsfiddle.net/9kkjuzjx/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was rly stupid one mistake... now it is:

```
function ajaxQuery(filename, postData, func_var) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/" + filename + ".php",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        success: func_var
    })
    postData = [];
    delete postData;
}
```

It was all about filename.